# How can I set gradle/test to work on the same docker environment where other CircleCi jobs are running

Tags: gradle, circleci, daml, circleci-workflows

I have a CircleCi's workflow that has 2 jobs. The second job (gradle/test) is dependent on the first one creating some files for it.
The problem is with the first job running inside a docker, and the second job (gradle/test) is not. Hence, the gradle/test is failing since it cannot find the files the first job created. How can I set gradle/test to work on the same space?

Here is a code of the workflow:

```
version: 2.1

orbs: 
  gradle: circleci/gradle@2.2.0

executors:
  daml-executor:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/openjdk:11.0-node
```

...

```
workflows:
  checkout-build-test:
    jobs:
      - daml_test:
          daml_sdk_version: "2.2.0"
          context: refapps
      - gradle/test:
          app_src_directory: prototype
          executor: daml-executor
          requires:
            - daml_test
```

Can anyone help me configure gradle/test correctly?

Answer (score 0):

CircleCI has a mechanism to share artifacts between jobs called "[workspace](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workspaces)" (well, they have multiple ones, but workspace is what you want here).

Concretely, you would add this at the end of your `daml_test` job definition, as an additional step:

```yaml
      - persist_to_workspace:
         root: /path/to/folder
         paths:
         - "*"
```

and that would add all the files from `/path/to/folder` to the workspace. On the other side, you can "mount" the workspace in your `gradle/test` job by adding something like this *before* the step where you need the files:

```yaml
      - attach_workspace:
         at: /whatever/mountpoint
```

I like to use `/tmp/workspace` for the path on both sides, but that's just personal preference.

Comment: Thanks Gary, but gradle/test does not have a specific job (like the daml_test). It is only mentioned in the workflows section. any idea how can I assign the "persist_to_workspace" in this case?

Comment: @AvrahamCohen Looking at [the code of the orb](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/gradle), it looks like it's just not meant to be used in a modular way. One possible approach here would be to just copy/paste the parts of the orb source that work for you.

Comment: Thanks @Gary for your comment. I actually completed the code as you said already, and it works.